# Codeigniter/php form template load modal for confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm passing input data to my controller like this:

```
if ($this->input->post('submit') === 'renew_prepaids_submit'){  
        
            if($this->affiliates_model->renew_doctor_pp($user_id, $this->input->post())){
                $type = $this->input->post('type');
                $amount = $this->input->post('amount');
               $pp_type = $this->input->post('doctor_case_fee_type'); 
               $doctor = $this->users_model->get_user($user_id);
               $doctor = object_to_array($doctor);
               $this->dev_email->pp_mailer($doctor,$type,$amount );
               
                
            } 
            
            redirect('/cases/thank_you');
        }
```

The view that contains the form template:

```
 <? $this->load->view('client/templates/form_horizontal', $prepaid_renewal_data); ?>
```

What I'm trying to do is, instead of doing redirect, I'd like to first have the submit button call a modal for verification, something like this:

```
<div id="create-visit-modal" class="modal hide fade create-visit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="create-visit-modal" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" style="margin-top:-8px;" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"> 
      <h1>Attention:</h1>
      <p style="text-align:justify;"></b>
      No returns or exchanges will be accepted. If you have any questions please call .
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
       <a class="btn btn-success"  style="float:left" href="https://dev.yikes/cases/renew_pp/664">Submit</a>
       <button class="btn btn-primary create-visit-modal-btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
```

```
<style>
    #alert{visibility: hidden !important; position: absolute;}
 </style>
```

So, the form will pass input data to the modal, the modal will then pass that input data to the controller etc.

Comment: ugh oh... is this for [healthcare.gov](http://healthcare.gov)? ;)

Comment: Why do you need the data in the modal ? Maybe you can catch the submit event and prevent it from submitting. You can after that, display your modal and when you click on your submit button in your modal, send the information from your form ?

Comment: I dont need the data I suppose, but how would i prevent submission using a form template?